# Listener not being called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am launching a `DialogFragment` from my Fragment and listening to an event in `MainActivity`  when the button is pressed in Dialog Fragment.

This is the listener interface defined in `DialogFragment` :

```
public interface NewDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(String data);
}
```

Instantiating the listener in `DialogFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        mListener = (NewDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
    }
}

@Override
public AlertDialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    currentActivity = getActivity();
    newDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(positiveButtonViewOnClickListener);
 ...
return newDialog;
}
```

Firing the listener when positive button in `DialogFragment`is clicked:

```
private DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveButtonOnClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        mListener.onDialogPositiveClick("positive");
    }
};
```

And then I capture the listener in `MainActivity` :

```
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(String status) {
    Fragment fragment = getVisibleFragment();
    if (fragment instanceof  NewListFragment) {
        ((NewListFragment)fragment).updateView();
    }
}
```

This works if I haven't changes the rotation of the device. But If I changes the rotation of the device and do the same thing again, the control never reaches `onDialogPositiveClick`.

What is that changes when device is rotated that could cause this?

Comment: Where are you setting positiveButtonOnClickListener to listen?

Comment: Inside the `DialogFragment` ?

Comment: You didn't post that part of the code.

Comment: I have tried to explain it. Its a huge Fragment. Also, Its common sense. Thats not the problem, That part and even this code works. The problem occurs when I rotate the device/change orientation.

Comment: Yes, but the problem could always be where and how you set it. Also, believe me, many people forget to set it. When you ask, try to cover all bases.

Comment: @lionscribe, If that was the case "This works if I haven't changes the rotation of the device." -- This wouldn't work , would it ?

Comment: Usually, but let's say you attached it in a function, or part of a function, that does not get called when rotated...

Comment: @lionscribe fair point. I have updated the code again. And let me add that all the calls in the fragments get called. I checked that with debugger points, But the call never reaches the `MainActivity`

Comment: @lionscribe, Would you like to take a dig at at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681619/both-fragment-in-actionbar-return-true-for-fragment-isvisible]?

Comment: onDialogPositiveClick would still be called.

Comment: It can also be a setRetainInstance issue, though I can't figure out exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Since the listener is the activity itself, you can just use it directly in the onClick via a call to getActivity(). You can put a try catch on the call to be safe. No need to set it to a variable.

Comment: Not sure If I understand that correctly. Do you mind posting an example?

Comment: private DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveButtonOnClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { ((NewDialogListener)(getActivity()).onDialogPositiveClick("positive"); } };

Comment: Reason being, I suspect that mListener is not valid for some reason after rotation.

Comment: possible, and it doesn't happen all the time. So your reasoning makes sense. I will try it out.