# Both Fragment in ActionBar return true for fragment.isVisible()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

In my `MainActivity` with `ActionBar` I listen to a listener from a `DialogFragment` and based on which Fragment of `ActionBar` i am on, I need to do some things.

I am using below code to get the current fragment and check which of the two `ActionBar` fragment i am on:

```
 private Fragment getVisibleFragment() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
                return fragment;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

but `fragment.isVisible()` returns true for both the fragments. Why would that be? Is there another flag I need to consider?

Below is my `FragmentPagerAdapter` implentation:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
Context context;
public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new ReceivedListFragment();
        case 1:
            return new SentListFragment();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 2 total pages.
    return 2;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return context.getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return context.getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: How are you adding your fragments? Can you show the part where you do the fragment transaction?

Comment: @jonDoe added it to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using a ViewPager and you need to find out which is the currently selected view. The problem in your approach, in my opinion, is that the viewpager keeps instance of at least two fragments. It seems you have two fragments only, both of the fragments are kept by the viewpager and which is why you get the **isVisible**  true for both the fragments.

If your only need is to get the currently selected fragment on the viewpager, please try this method from the viewpager class:

```
mViewPagerInstance.getCurrentItem();
```

which will give you the currently selected fragment index.

Another way would be to add a **PageChangeListener** for your viewpager and then listen to page change events:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{
  private int curPage;

  private static class MFragChangeListener extends SimpleOnPageChangeListener{
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
               curPage = position;
  }
} 

  ........... /* Rest of your code */

mViewPagerInstance.setOnPageChangeListener(new MFragChangeListener());
/* Now access curPage to get the current selected page index whenever you need it. */
```

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117523/how-do-you-get-the-current-page-number-of-a-viewpager-for-android) SO post as well.

Comment: that works. I had a backup in my mind :  `private Fragment getVisibleFragment(Class<?> fragmentType) {...if(fragment != null && fragment.isVisible() &&  fragmentType == ReceivedListFragment.class) { return fragment; }...}` but I wanted a right solution. Thank you

Comment: Yes, we should always use the best solution whenever possible. Hacks might fail in  unexpected situations and we will have break our heads then. I'm glad this worked for you!

Comment: How can I get the instance of fragment now? Doing something like `mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(currentFragmentIndex)` return a new instance of the fragment

Comment: I believe you can keep an array/list of your fragments and just retreive it using the index.